# Работа с одинаковыми классами в JQuery по отдельности

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть такая разметка.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').hover(function() {
    $('.box img').css({
      "display": "none"
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="boxContent">
    <div class="box">
      <img class="zxczxc" src="img/S-1.png" height="85" width="85" alt="" />
      <p>Введение</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/ico-binoculars.svg?v=d4dbaac4eec9g" height="85" width="85" />
      <p>Введение</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box ">
      <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/ico-binoculars.svg?v=d4dbaac4eec9" height="85" width="85" />
      <p>Введение</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/ico-binoculars.svg?v=d4dbaac4eec9" height="85" width="85" />
      <p>Введение</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="img/S-1.png" height="85" width="85" />
      <p>Введение</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Блок img повторяется много раз.Как сделать так, что бы при наведение на img функция срабатывала только в блоке на который навели.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box img').hover(function() {
    $(this).css({
      "display": "none"
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="boxContent">
    <div class="box">
      <img class="zxczxc" src="img/S-1.png" height="85" width="85" alt="" />
      <p>Введение</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/ico-binoculars.svg?v=d4dbaac4eec9g" height="85" width="85" />
      <p>Введение</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box ">
      <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/ico-binoculars.svg?v=d4dbaac4eec9" height="85" width="85" />
      <p>Введение</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/ico-binoculars.svg?v=d4dbaac4eec9" height="85" width="85" />
      <p>Введение</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="img/S-1.png" height="85" width="85" />
      <p>Введение</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPD. после комментария**

```js
$(".item").hover(function() {
  $(this).find("img").css({
    "display": "none"
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="#"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="#"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="#"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="#"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="#"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: А как сделать что бы при наведение на .box исчезала картинка только в наведенном box?

Comment: @Zombieсat, обновил ответ, посмотрите. Чуть переделал вёрстку, но смысл один.

Answer (score 0):

тогда уж

```
$(this).find('img').css({
  "display": "none";
});
```